# Plotting Excel data with Julia

Tags: plotting, julia

Let me first be clear that I'm still new to Julia.

I need to plot time series data contained in an Excel file using Julia. So far I couldn't find any packages for that. The only workaround I found was to save the Excel as a CSV file and then plot the data using DataFrames and Gadfly.

I know that this can be done easily with Pyplot in Python and that a version is also available for Julia, but still I couldn't figure how to do it in Julia.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to options to extract data from Excel documents:

1. [ExcelReaders](https://github.com/davidanthoff/ExcelReaders.jl)
2. [Taro](https://github.com/aviks/Taro.jl)

Once you have the data you can use Gadfly.